# Android eclipse: is it possible to change decimal format to int?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm making an application about PMT function. And I got stuck at some point. I have a function that will convert a number input from EditText to a decimal, e.g. 10000000 to 10,000,000. And there is another which clashing with this converter function. The another one handles 3 EditTexts, 1 EditText for price input, 2nd EditText for percentage and the last one will calculate (automatically) the result of them both which is use integer.

Here is the code of number converter

```
public void makeDecimal(View v) {
    ethint1.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

    DigitsKeyListener dkl = new DigitsKeyListener(true, true);
    ethint1.setKeyListener(dkl);

    ethint1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private String current = "";

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String userInput = s.toString();

            if (!userInput.toString().equals(current)) {
                ethint1.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                String cleanString = userInput.replaceAll("[,]", "");

                if (cleanString.length() > 0) {
                    double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                    String formated = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance().format(parsed);

                    current = formated;
                    ethint1.setText(formated);
                    ethint1.setSelection(formated.length());
                } else {
                    ethint1.setText(cleanString);
                    ethint1.setSelection(cleanString.length());
                }

                ethint1.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code for the calculation

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simulasikredit);
    ethint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethint);
    etpersen2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpersen);
    textvDP1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textvDP);
    bkalkulasi1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bkalkulasi);

    etpersen2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String text1 = ethint1.getText().toString();

            if (text1.length() != 0) {
                int input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);

                int input2 = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());

                int output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                textvDP1.setText("" + output /*+ ""*/);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However, having them both my app will crash. If I use only one of them the calculator or the number converter, it works.
Is there a way to make them both work?
Note: I have all these codes in 1 class, my main class

Comment: Please provide stacktrace. You can find it in logcat output.

Comment: i mentioned, these functions clashing each other cause one use integer(input(string to int))and the other use decimal format(input(it's actually string converted to decimal)).i am only able to use one of the function, can't use them both

Comment: if i give an input on price edittext(edittext1(the variable here is ethint1)),and then fill the 2nd edittext(the percentage) it will crash, and the log cat says unable to parse "1,000" as a number...Note:i input 1000 on edittext1 it will be 1,000